# SDL 2.0 Key repeat and delay

Tags: c++, keyboard-events, sdl-2

I'm having a problem with SDL 2.0 keyboard input in pong-like game. When I order to move to the left by pressing left arrow, it is processed by SDL_PollEvents() and responds correctly if the key was pressed once. However, if I keep the key pressed, I get a short delay (as long as Windows key repeat delay) before moving continuously.

Here is function processing events:

```
void Event::PlayerEvent (Player &player)
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent (&mainEvent))
    {
        switch (mainEvent.type)
        {
            case SDL_KEYDOWN :
                switch (mainEvent.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_ESCAPE :
                        gameRunning = false;
                        break;
                    case SDLK_LEFT :
                        player.moving = player.left;
                        break;
                    case SDLK_RIGHT :
                        player.moving = player.right;
                }
                break;
            case SDL_QUIT :
                gameRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: After all, I managed to fix this issue by calling 
SystemParametersInfo (SPI_SETKEYBOARDDELAY, 0, 0, 0) at the start of the program and SystemParametersInfo (SPI_SETKEYBOARDDELAY, 1, 0, 0) at the end, to return to standard key repeat delay.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/26_motion/index.php) tutorial. The author use 2 tricks: (1) key press affect object velocity instead of position; (2) detect key down and up and filtered repeats. So when key down, velocity increased. Once increased, continue pressing won't change it so object continue to move. When key up, velocity decreased and object stop moving. This may help with your delay problem.

Comment: It decreased the delay a bit, but still it wasn't what I was looking for.

Comment: After few tweaks in the code, I must say that this tutorial is proper solution to my problem. I got rid of delay. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

For game movement, you would typically not use events, but rather use states.

Try using SDL_GetKeyboardState() outside of the event loop:

```
const Uint8* keystates = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

...

if(keystates[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT])
    player.moving = player.left;
else if(keystates[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT])
    player.moving = player.right;
```

Comment: Thanks for hint, I'll definitely use keystates in future, however it did not solve problem with key delay.

Comment: Even using SPI_SETKEYBOARDDELAY (which is, of course, not cross-platform), you are only guaranteed to get down to a 250ms delay.  There would be no delay when using key states.

If you want to use key events without a delay, you need to respond to them differently.  On keydown, set the movement.  On keyup, stop the movement.  Also note that you can ignore repeated keydowns by checking event.key.repeat.

Comment: delays are there becos of the system keyboard driver...you have to separate the keyboard delay from your game mechanic...up key means for instance that the updirection is set to true, and while it is, you can update your player position at each frame

Comment: I don't recommend using else ifs in that situation when you want to move. specifically in Game Development. for example, You won't be able to combine W+A for moving up-left automatically. It means you will have to implement them all yourself like `else if(W_pressed && A_pressed) move.up_left;`. I just recommend using only **if**s and everything would be naturally okay.

Answer (score 2):

using `SPI_SETKEYBOARDDELAY` is not a good approach. This way your game will not be protable anymore since its only available on `Windows`.

Instead you should use like menthiond in an answer before `SDL_GetKeyboardState`.

Howeve be aware that you still have to collect the `SDL_PollEvent`. Otherwise `SDL_GetKeyboardState` will be always empty.

So it should be like this:

```
//...
SDL_Event sdlEvent;
while (SDL_PollEvent(&sdlEvent)) {
    if (sdlEvent.type == SDL_QUIT) {
        //..
    }
}

const Uint8* keystates = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

if(keystates[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT]) {
    //...
}
if(keystates[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT]) {
    /...
}
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

simple as that

```
int vertical = 0;
int horizontal = 0;

float x = 500;
float y = 500;

float speed = 5.0;
```

in your sdl loop:

```
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            {
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_LEFT:  horizontal=-1; break;
                    case SDLK_RIGHT: horizontal = 1; break;
                    case SDLK_UP:    vertical=-1; break;
                    case SDLK_DOWN:  vertical=+1; break;
                }
                break;
            }
            case SDL_KEYUP:
            {
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                case SDLK_LEFT:  horizontal = 0; break;
                case SDLK_RIGHT: horizontal = 0; break;
                case SDLK_UP:    vertical = 0; break;
                case SDLK_DOWN:  vertical = 0; break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    x += horizontal * speed;
    y += vertical * speed;
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the SDL_GetKeyboardState capturing outside of - while (SDL_PollEvent (&mainEvent)), that works fine.

Comment: The answer by Jonny D already suggests this approach, so I don't think this answer adds anything new.