# SDL lag when pressing certain keys but not others

Tags: c, sdl

I have a square on the screen and I want it to move to the right by 5 pixels every 25ms if a particular key is held down. I don't understand why it works fine with some keys (for example up) but doesn't work as expected with other keys (for example a). By not working properly I mean that instead of taking 6 seconds to cross the whole screen, it takes about 10 seconds and the square takes a while to stop moving after I've stopped pressing the key.

Here's the full code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define LARGEUR 1200
#define HAUTEUR 800
#define DELAI_RAFRAICHISSEMENT 25

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{
    int tempsActuel = 0, tempsPrecedent = 0;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK) != 0 )
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"Echec de l'initialisation de la SDL   (%s)\n",SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_Window* window;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("1 2 3 Piano",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, LARGEUR, HAUTEUR, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Rect ecran = {0, 0, LARGEUR, HAUTEUR};
    SDL_Rect carre = {0, 775, 25, 25};
    SDL_Rect carreDroite = {0, 775, 0, 25};
    SDL_Rect carreGauche = {0, 775, 0, 25};

    bool continuer = true;

    while(continuer){
        tempsActuel = SDL_GetTicks();
        if (tempsActuel - tempsPrecedent < DELAI_RAFRAICHISSEMENT){
            SDL_Delay(DELAI_RAFRAICHISSEMENT - (tempsActuel - tempsPrecedent));
        }
        tempsPrecedent = SDL_GetTicks();

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255,255,255,0);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &ecran);

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0,0,0,0);

        if(carre.x <= 1175)
            SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &carre);
        else{
            carreDroite.x = carre.x;
            carreDroite.w = LARGEUR - carre.x;
            carreGauche.w = 25 - carreDroite.w;
            SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &carreDroite);
            SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &carreGauche);
        }

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

        SDL_PollEvent(&event);

        switch(event.type){
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_a)
                    carre.x = (carre.x+5) % LARGEUR;
                else if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
                    continuer = false;
                break;

            case SDL_QUIT:
                continuer = false;
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Like I said, it works fine if I replace SDLK_a with SDLK_UP. There are very few keys with which it works as expected.

Comment: Probably related to [key repeat delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373203/sdl-2-0-key-repeat-and-delay)

Comment: You need to call `SDL_PollEvent` in a loop until it returns null, to empty the event queue each frame.

Comment: @User7231 Thanks using the following code inside the while loop did the trick : SDL_PumpEvents();

        const Uint8* keystates = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

        if(keystates[SDL_SCANCODE_Q])
            carre.x = (carre.x+5) % LARGEUR;
        else if(keystates[SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE])
            continuer = false;

Comment: Just realized I should use  const Uint8* keystates = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL); outside of the while loop. Anyway It works :)